# RSolve for system of equations and matrix power

Tags: functions, recursion

I have a matrix

```
 a = {{3, -2}, {2, -2}};
```

We can easily find the n-th power, $A^n$ using

```
 MatrixPower[a,n]
```

We can also find the matrix power by using eigenvalues and eigenvectors for diagonalization

$$A^n = P D^n P^{-1}$$

Another approach uses the [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem), because all polynomials satisfy their own characteristic polynomial. This means
$$(A-2)(A+1)=A^2-A-2I=\mathbf{0}\implies A^2=A+2I$$$$\implies A^n=A^{n-1}+2A^{n-2}$$

Using the substitution $a_n=A^n$, we now have the recurrence relation $$a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2},a_0=I,a_1=A$$

Solving this through standard means of solving recurrence relations, we obtain
$$A^n=a_n=\left(-\frac13A+\frac23I\right)\cdot(-1)^n+\left(\frac13A+\frac13I\right)\cdot2^n$$
$$=\pmatrix{-\frac13\cdot(-1)^n+\frac43\cdot2^n&&\frac23\cdot(-1)^n-\frac23\cdot2^n\\
-\frac23\cdot(-1)^n+\frac23\cdot2^n&&\frac43\cdot(-1)^n-\frac13\cdot2^n}$$

Mathematica's [*RSolve*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) command can solve  systems of equations. I tried the following but it failed.

```
  a0 = IdentityMatrix[2]; 
  a1 = {{3, -2}, {2, -2}};
  sol = RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a0 + 2 . a[n - 1], a[0] == a0, a[1] == a1}, 
  Element[a, Matrices[{2, 2}]], n];
  a[n] /. sol[[1]] // MatrixForm
```

Is there a way to get RSolve to solve this matrix recurrence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) you used `a0` where you should have `a[n]`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a0 = IdentityMatrix[2];
a1 = {{3, -2}, {2, -2}};
sol = RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + 2*a[n - 1], a[0] == a0, a[1] == a1}, 
  Element[a, Matrices[{2, 2}]], n]

(* {{a -> Function[{n}, {{1/3 (-(-1)^n + 2^(2 + n)), 
      2/3 ((-1)^n - 2^n)}, {-(2/3) ((-1)^n - 2^n), 1/3 (4 (-1)^n - 2^n)}}]}} *)

(a[n] /. sol[[1]]) == MatrixPower[a1, n] // Simplify

(* True *)
```